# GUI to view data in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, user-interface, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

We are using a PostgreSQL database within Cloud SQL. We are using a private IP address and are accessing our database in our pods with the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy).

We are now looking for a way to quickly and easily access data in those databases. As far as I can tell there is nothing built in that supports this.

What ways are there to install a (ideally web based) GUI with which we can view our data?

Comment: There are zillions of SQL products on the market. Do a Google Search and select one that meets your needs. StackOverflow does not recommend third party products. Questions asking for opinions are not supported on StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JohnHanley, This is not a helpful comment.  Try searching for "Cloud SQL table viewer" or other phrases someone trying to accomplish this task would search for and you will see that if there are zillions of products that fill this need, they are very well hidden.

Comment: @ubiquibacon - Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I guess I read questions like this differently. It was clear to me that the OP knew what he wanted (to view data in Cloud SQL), was unable to find a way to do that, thus reached out to the community. Sometimes just knowing *what* to search for (i.e. a specific term) is immensely helpful. I didn't realize until reading one of the answers below that MySQL or pgAdmin worked for any DBs other than their namesake, just knowing that got me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are now accessing Google's Cloud SQL via a [bastion host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host) from our own developer machines.

Answer (score 1):

You can install pgAdmin.

First, we need to import the repository key.

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl ca-certificates
$ curl https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

And create the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list file. The distributions are called codename-pgdg. In our example should be bionic-pgdg.

```
$ deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main
```

To determine the codename of your distribution you can run the lsb_release -c command.

After this, you need to update the package lists, and install the pgadmin package:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install pgadmin4
```

Then, you only need to run the pgadmin4 command:

```
$ pgadmin4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Data Studio. One way to do it is creating a view in the DB which collects the information to visualize the report. Then, create a data source in Data Studio and select the view that contains that information. That data source should be connected with reports/graphics.

Currently, the only possible connections to Data Studio are the following:
1. Google Cloud SQL for MySQL
2. MySQL
3. PostgreSQL

Here's a [guide](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020436?hl=en&ref_topic=7332343) for you to start with the connection.